what is expectedFees and expectedWeight in a block and why its changing frequently?
what is expectedFees and expectedWeight in a block and why its changing frequently ?
https://mempool.space/api/v1/block/00000000000000000001c680ee86b8eaa43c94ac9012f4d2dcbfa9f45beadf06
when i last check the "expectedFees":27191335,"expectedWeight":3991985

I think it's a mempool.space thing. They calculate the expected block using the blocktemplate that their own node gives them and from there they take that information. The difference with the real data is because the real blocks are not always the same as they think they are, you can see the match in the "similarity" parameter. I made the api call several times and it didn't change, and I understand that it shouldn't change.
